# Switching app "states" using QMainWindow as superclass

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm attempting to run different modes/states of my app, for example having a menu which can go to a game state then highscore and from those two back to menu.

A solution I tried was using the autogenerated class `QMainWindow` as a superclass for creating the classes `Menu` and `Game` to start with. In `QMainWindow` I later want to create a `QMainWindow`, fill it with a `Menu` or `Game` and in eg. `QMainWindow.paintEvents()` call `Menu.paintEvent()` through polymophfism.

Now I know that I can't create a `QMainWindow` in another `QMainWindow` but would this idea work with yet another subclass called `states` or somthing inbetween the existing super/subclass(es)?

I was able to run just `Game` by itself (instead of `QMainWindow`) so the inheritance is probably done right. But when trying to create and run only a `Game` in `QMainWindow` it gave me a `sigsegv` at `QMainWindow`'s constructor (which I have not changed and runs completely fine bby itself if empty). I've solved the problem with the classes including themselves in one another so that's not the problem either.

Comment: 1) To get useful help with the sigsegv (and the rest of your question), some minimal code would be helpful to show what you've tried. 2) You can create a QMainWindow in another QMainWindow, nothing is stopping you. 3) Multiple QMainWindows are rarely needed, and based on your description, you possibly don't need even one. That class comes with convenient default functionality & layout, but if you do not make use of its menu bar, docking widgets, etc., you are probably better off by extending a plain QWidget to use as the main window of your application.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I basically have the QMainWindow atm but without all the menus and extra features so I shouold probably look into how to use QWidget instead.I think also I can solve my main problem by having a `State` class that recieves what the QMainWindow/QWidget recieves and just forwards it to its subclasses (without having `State` be a subclass itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by making a superclass "State" for menu and game (without making State a subclass to QMainWindow) which is called by QMainWindow for each operation.

This is essentially the "states" pattern which I realise existed after the implementation.